# Why does the Node.JS community generally favor NoSQL over relational databases?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Why is MongoDB usually used in conjunction with NodeJS?, Is it just coincidental or are there good engineering reasons behind this combination?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct correlation between nodejs and mongo.

In particular mongo has [drivers](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/) for the following languages:

- C
- C++
- C#
- Java
- Node.js
- Perl
- PHP
- Python
- Ruby
- Scala

The only correlation that I can find is that using nodejs queries are more similar to the same query written in the console of mongo than other languages (below an example in nodejs and in java).

In node js:

```
...
db.collection('restaurants').insertOne( {
  "name":"Pizza Roma",
  "city":"Rome",
  "country":"Italy"
});
...
```

In java

```
...
Document restaurant = new Document("name", "Pizza Roma")
           .append("city", "Rome")
           .append("country", "Italy");

db.getCollection("restaurants").insertOne(document);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of MongoDB documents is JSON-like.

JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is syntactically identical to the code for creating JavaScript objects, so creating JSON structures from objects and parsing JSON to objects is really easy in JavaScript. You can directy insert a JavaScript object structure into MongoDB.

Other than that, MongoDB has Drivers for a vast array of languages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct relation between Node.js and Mongodb. MongoDB is a
document based database which will give data as a JSON directly and it is schema less.To develop the rapid applications now a days MEAN stack apps are very famous.Actually Node.js is not limited to MongoDB it can be connected with different databases.